# Adding a headphone jack to furniture

Tags: wiring, furniture

I'd like to screw a headphone jack receptacle to the front of my desk, and have the female adapter of the extension in my laptop (which is hidden in one of the drawers).

I'm unsure what exactly to even Google to find the part(s) that I need to secure the extension to the desk. Any tips?

[image: example]

Comment: You could get a sub-miniature phone jack from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/2-5mm-Stereo-Sub-Mini-Chassis-Mount/dp/B004GIDV62) and install it in a small plastic project box that you then attach to the desk.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this is a "shopping question", and as such is off-topic here.

Comment: The exact part you want seems to be available google desk mounted headphone jack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest option is to use a headphone extension cord.  You can secure one end to the desk using a couple of cable ties that form an X over the top of the extension cord end.  Or you could use a screw-mount cable tie, or a normal cable tie along with a cable tie mount.

If cable ties aren't your thing, you could buy a panel mount headphone jack and install it in a small box, such as a mint tin, which you can screw to the desk leg.